Uploading managed_file from custom form always inserts file as temporary://. How to move to private://?
While trying to create a custom form (using form api) in Drupal 7, I wanted the user to be able to upload a file.
In my hook_formname_submit() function, I was saving the file, but in my database it was always showing the URI as temporary://, when I actually needed it in a private:// directory.
It took me a while but I figured out what all to do; answer below.  I hope this helps someone out there.

I cobbled this solution together thanks to different answers on this question: Change individual file from public to private and vice-versa
In my hook.._submit($form, $form_state) function, I have code that looks like this...
  $fid = intval($form_state['values'][$key]);
  
  // For unknown reasons (a possible bug in Drupal 7) $val will sometimes(?) be 
  // zero in form_state['values'], if
  // submitted by an anonymous user, and if the element is inside of a fieldset!
  // SO, we will also look for the fid in _POST if it's zero in form_state.
        
  if ($fid === 0) {
    $fid = intval($_POST[$key]['fid']);  
  }

  // Handle files            
  $file = file_load($fid);
  if ($file) {
    
    // If the file is in temporary://, then move to private://attached_files/surveys/
    if (strstr($file->uri, "temporary://")) {
      
      $original = $file->uri;
      
      $destination = str_replace("temporary://", "", $file->uri);
      $destination = "private://attached_files/surveys/" . $destination;
      
      // Must use copy if we are going from temporary to private.          
      $new_file = file_copy($file, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
                
      // Delete the original
      file_delete($file);
      
      // Replace with new one
      $file = $new_file;
      
      
    }
    
    // Change status to permanent.
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    $file->display = 1;  // Required to save correctly
    // Save.
    file_save($file);

Importantly, you MUST use file_copy() and not file_move(), if you are going from a public or temporary location to a private one.
